# Why do object assignments refer to memory locations when primitive types don't?

Tags: java, object, variable-assignment, primitive

I have a bit of an odd question regarding how primitive types work in Java. When using Objects when you assign an ObjectA to be ObjectB be like such

```
Rectangle ObjectB = new Rectangle();
ObjectA = ObjectB;
```

Any calls to ObjectA refer now to ObjectB's memory location. However when using integers or other primitive types this is not the case. For example

```
int x = 3;
int y = x;
int x = 5;
return y;
```

y will return 3, the value of x when y was initialized.

The question I have is why does assignment for objects create references in memory, whereas primitives make a copy of the values of each other? Other than the fact that this is useful, how is this implemented in Java?

I'd appreciate anyone who can provide me a greater understanding of how assignment works between primitive types and objects.

Comment: [Is Java “pass-by-reference” or “pass-by-value”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)

Comment: Java has two types of variables. Primitives and reference only. When you copy a primitive, it is the primitive values which is copied, when you copy a reference, it is the reference value which is copied.  There is no "assignment for objects"

Answer (score 7):

The *exact same thing* is done whether the variables are of primitive type or reference type: The **value** held in the variable is copied to the other variable.

The only difference is that the value held in a variable with a reference type is a *reference* to the actual thing (the object), not the actual thing itself, whereas the value in the variable for primitive types *is* the actual thing (the primitive value).

Say you have:

```
int a = 5;
```

That's a bit like Joe having a piece of paper (the variable `a`) with 5 written on it.

Now:

```
int b = a;
```

The *value* in `a` is copied into `b`. That's a bit like Mary coming along, getting out a piece of paper, and copying down what's on Joe's piece of paper (the number 5).

Now, say you have:

```
Map a = new HashMap();
```

It's a bit like Joe having a piece of paper with his address written on it. The piece of paper is the variable `a`; the `HashMap` object is his house.

Now:

```
Map b = a;
```

The *value* in `a` is copied into `b`. It's like Mary coming along and getting out a piece of paper and copying Joe's address from his piece of paper onto it. The *house* hasn't been copied, just the information about where it is.

That's what an object reference is: Information (like a number) telling the JVM where the object is in memory.

I go into it in some detail [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34917452/why-does-creating-an-array-from-primitives-copy-them/34917487#34917487) (Java), and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34534973/157247) (which is about JavaScript, but the concept of values, variables, and object references is the same in the two languages [and many others]).